# Issue with sql select command on button

Tags: c#, sql

I have a database named apps and I want to make a form for seaching from my database table books. I made a listbox with items "author" and " book name" and a textbox in which the user will type which author or book name they wants to search. Here is my code :

```
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=****;";
    MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    string mySelectQuery = "";
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, constring);
    if (listBox3.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        mySelectQuery =  "select * from apps.books where book_author LIKE @name ";
    }
    else if (listBox3.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        mySelectQuery = "select * from apps.books where book_name LIKE @name ";
    }

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + textBox1.Text + "%");
    MessageBox.Show(mySelectQuery);
    conDatabase.Close();
```

The problem when i press the search button, the message shows "Select * from (...) " instead of the components of the table that i want to find. Could you help me?

Comment: `mySelectQuery` is string, what are you expecting? You should execute this string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move this line

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, constring);
```

below the if statement.  Like it is now you make the query with whatever is in the string before you modify it.

You should add a check to make sure the select index is one of the two you expect

```
else
{
    mySelectQuery = "Select 'Invalid dropdown selection'";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i made the changes you suggested, but i still see the same message select *(..) when i click the button :(

Comment: @Juniorita - that is the EXACT message you see when you click the button?  that is your EXACT code for the on click handler?  Please show the full function in your code above.

Comment: i figured out what was wrong, mySelectQuery is a string , and i was giving the messagebox the value of mySelectQuery.. Thanks for help